# No Way to Install Custom Extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have followed the guide to create a custom extension using this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops.

I am able to push to a publisher successfully. I have also shared the extension with my organization and can see the extension listed when I go to `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_admin`.

However, when I click the extension, I click the 'Get it Free' button, and I only see a 'Download' button. I do not see an 'Install' button, which is what I have seen in various screenshots.

When clicking the 'Download' button, I get the .vsix file, and do not see a way to install this in my project.

Here are images of my workflow:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you not seeing the **"Select an Azure DevOps organization"** heading and the drop down to select your organization?

Comment: @JoshGust yes I do, and I am able to select my organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I was not a member of the Project Collection Administrator group. After being added to this I was able to install the extension.

Comment: I was in this group, but what's really important is that you are not in a group that has a Deny. The Deny will take precedence over any Allow.